# How to use db in erlang correctly?

Tags: architecture, mongodb, erlang

I write some example on erlang and mongodb. As driver for mongodb I use [emongo](https://github.com/JacobVorreuter/emongo). Problem is if I make connection in one module I can not reuse this connection in different modules. In C/C++ or other objective languages I can make singleton and use it. How can I reuse open connection in erlang?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to re-use the pool ID from any part of your application.

In module A:

```
emongo:insert(test, SomeCollection, Document).
```

In module B:

```
emongo:insert(test, AnotherCollection, AnotherDocument).
```

As long as you keep using the same id (in this case, `test`) either by hard coding it into the different modules or by sending it in a message, you should be able to use the library from any part of the application.